# Tornado + Momoko. Growing response time

Tags: python, postgresql, tornado, momoko

When we're doing load testing on our tornado server with command:

```
ab -n 500 -c 100 http://<hostname>/api/stats/?events=691
```

After first 400 requests (at speed 200 rps) - last 100 takes a lot of time.

We've got following results in log:

```
[I 140314 12:25:19 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 12.92ms
[I 140314 12:25:19 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 21.22ms
[I 140314 12:25:19 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 28.75ms
[I 140314 12:25:20 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 3021.00ms
[I 140314 12:25:24 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 6403.66ms
[I 140314 12:25:24 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 6411.02ms
[I 140314 12:25:24 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 6417.97ms
[I 140314 12:25:24 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 6420.90ms
[I 140314 12:25:24 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 6426.83ms
[I 140314 12:25:24 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 6439.17ms
[I 140314 12:25:24 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 6442.40ms
[I 140314 12:25:24 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 6445.59ms
[I 140314 12:25:24 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 6449.05ms
[I 140314 12:25:24 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 6445.53ms
[I 140314 12:25:30 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 12985.94ms
[I 140314 12:25:30 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 12871.76ms
[I 140314 12:25:30 web:1462] 200 GET /api/stats/?events=691 (127.0.0.1) 12760.86ms
```

Momoko has following connection settings:

```
db_min_con = 5
db_max_con = 70
```

We've limit on postgresql to 300 connections and same limit on pgpool.

Why response time growing at the end of test? Where to dig?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to recreate this issue with plain sync `psycopg2`? May be this [github issue](https://github.com/FSX/momoko/issues/93) will provide a hint?

Comment: We've rid off from pgpool and have no performance issues at the moment. However, will check it out on next inspection of performance.